# sp not handling TextView text well

Tags: android, textview

I have a text view:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/attribution"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/creative_commons"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

On xhdpi it displays nicely, in one line:
**Sounds used under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 license**

However, in hdpi, it looks like this:
**Sounds used under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0

license**

I thought `sp` (as in `32sp`) was supposed to handle screen density.
What do I need to do to correct this?

To address a couple of the suggestions:
Using `dp` makes no difference. This is not surprising since `sp` is `dp` + user font preferences
Using `singleLine` does indeed force it to a single line, which then runs off the screen.

Comment: sp handles screen density, not size. Are the screen sizes the same for those devices you tested that on?

Comment: use dimens.xml file to give separate TextSize for different screen sizes.

Comment: or use ellipsize and singleline to handle this problem nicely

Comment: You can use `dp` instead of `sp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this problem is to use Android resource qualifier mechanism. You can specify alternative layout for screens with different sizes. I assume 32sp is too big for devices with smaller display in your case. Here is how you fix it with Android resource qualifier:

1. Create a folder, res/layout-sw480dp
2. Keep the same layout file in res/layout folder
3. Copy the same layout file to the new folder res/layout-sw480dp, and modify the font size to be smaller (any size that looks good for phone)

Please note, "480" is chosen for screen with 480x800 mdpi. You can use "320" for handsets with 240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, or 480x800 hdpi.

Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html if you need information in detail.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The smaller device I am testing is a 1st gen Nexus 7, so screen dimensions are 1280×800. The larger device is a Nexus 10, 2560x1600.

Comment: So do I create a folder `res/layout-sw1280dp` for the Nexus 7?

Comment: Yes, please give res/layout-sw1280dp a try.

Comment: res/layout-sw1280dp had no effect on the Nexus 7, but if I do res/layout-sw480dp, then it works.

Comment: the layout in  res/layout-sw480dp is used by both the 7 and 10 (no surprise in retrospect). So what I did instead was create a folder res/layout-sw800dp. The layout in this is used by the 10, and the 7 uses the layout in res/layout

Answer (score 0):

SP is similar to DP, but further modified to text size specifics like user settings.

However, DP/SP are 'brackets' and a number of resolutions and screen sizes fit into these same brackets and the resulting size isn't always going to fit perfectly.

As such you should concentrate on making your layouts adaptive, this is especially true if you're localising your application as text will be different lengths in other languages.